# how to use different module in zend framework 2 (zf2)

Tags: zend-framework2

I have 2 different module in project
1)Album
2)User

I want use some classes of User module in 'Album' Module.

Please help me how I can configure it.

Thanks and Regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service Classes should be accessible via the `ServiceManager`. In case Classes are made available there, either as `factories` or `invokables`, you should be able to call them from your `Controller` like this:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('name-of-your-service');
```

Otherwise if it's only classes you need to use, you can simply import and use them like

```
namespace Othermodule;

use My\Module\Class\Name;

class OtherModuleClass {
    public function someAction()
    {
        new Name();

        // Or fully qualified inline
        new \Third\Module\Class\Name();
    }
}
```